# Print folder of files from Excel to PDF bypassing prompt windows

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am trying to print all the files in a folder to PDF. At the moment my code prints the files in loop, however it asks the location to save the files. I would like to bypass this option for it to run until all files have been printed. Thanks.

Here the code:

```
Sub Print_forms_PDFs_folder()

' Read_folder Macro
'
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wsh As Worksheet

    
    cwin1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show Then
            strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "No folder selected!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        strPath = strPath & "\"
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsm*")
    Do While strFile <> ""
                                
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=strPath & strFile, ReadOnly:=True, CorruptLoad:=xlmExtractData
            
            Sheets("UCS-Chart").Select

        'From interpreted_to_pdf()
        '
            Dim CurrentFileName As String
            CurrentFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

            
            Application.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF on Ne02:"
    
   
            fName_ini = Left(CurrentFileName, Len(CurrentFileName) - 16) + "interpreted.pdf"
    
            Do
                fName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
                InitialFileName:=fName_ini, _
                fileFilter:="Text Files (*.pdf), *.pdf")
            Loop Until fName <> False
  
       
            Range("L3").Select
        
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, PrintToFile:=True, Collate:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, PrToFileName:=fName

    'Close file
            'Windows(cwin2).Activate
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            strFile = Dir
            Application.Calculate
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have tried several options, but keep getting the prompt window.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking "Microsoft Print to PDF" calls a "Virtual" printer and is especially designed for **user interaction** from "Any Application". Thus it is en**forced** to a PortPrompt or PromptPort, (which you should NOT adjust).

There are simple ways to set a "PromptPort" to a PDF FilePort and whilst I could suggest that as a solution for some applications, it would be inappropriate in this case.

MS Office VBApplications have their own direct method of sending data directly to a PDF FilePort by "SaveAs" function.

There are many generic examples (including here in StackOverflow) of how to set the selected data range etc. to a FILE.PDF

Answer (score -1):

If you want the user to select output folder only once, use the `msoFileDialogFolderPicker` option:

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If .Show = -1 Then
        sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
```

and then use `sfolder` in `fname_ini` to propose a default save path like

```
fName_ini = sFolder & Left(CurrentFileName, ...
```